# AWS S3 movie playback not working (black screen)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video, mp4

When I try to open mp4-files from my AWS S3 bucket in any web browser, the screen is showing a webplayer playing the file, but the sceen is just black.

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV5y6.png)

I only get it to work on my laptop using EDGE-browser and on my android phone which asks me to open the file in VLC-player.

How can I get around this and get it to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your MP4 object in S3 have Content-Type, Content-Disposition, and/or Content-Encoding metadata? What are their values?

Comment: Thanks for the response! 1 metadata value is set: Type = System defined; Key = Content Type; Value =  video/mp4.

Comment: Seems OK. Are you using an S3 pre-signed URL for this video, or is it public? Are you sure that the URL is/was valid (and not expired if pre-signed) in the failing case?

Comment: I'm opening it as root user from s3 console. Also same result with other users.

Comment: What browser/platform is it failing to play on?  What codecs are used in the video?

Comment: Aaahhh, of course thanks Anon Coward! I was so sure we'd left the year 2002 behind I didn't check. I've encoded using H.265 which is very rarely supported (only Edge, Windows and my HP laptop). After converting to H.264 it works like a charm. I'm very thankful!!!

Answer (score 1):

What browser/platform is it failing to play on? What codecs are used in the video? If you are using H.265 which is very rarely supported you can try converting the files to H.264.

Comment: this answer solved my issue...video was encoded H.265.
using VLC i was able to convert to H.264 and now videos play from the bucket through my Roku channel.